# In programming for Estimote Beacons, how do we retrieve the actual name of the Beacon?

Tags: java, android, sdk, estimote

I tried Beacon.getName(), but it only returned "EST", even though I named the beacon something else. I was sure to check the beacon with the remote app on my phone as well to make sure the name was changed.

Follow Up:

What command should I use to retrieve tags and geolocation on the beacon? It doesn't seem to be in the API

Answer (score 0):

The [`getName`](http://estimote.github.io/Android-SDK/JavaDocs/com/estimote/sdk/Beacon.html#getName--) method of the `Beacon` class gives you the name as advertised by the beacon itself, i.e., the name contained in the advertising packet. It's the same name you'll see when you run any "raw" Bluetooth scanner, e.g., [nRF Master Control Panel](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=no.nordicsemi.android.mcp&hl=en), and for Estimote Beacons is always "EST" or "estimote."

If you're instead interested in the name of the beacon as configured in Estimote Cloud, you need to use the [`fetchBeaconDetails`](http://estimote.github.io/Android-SDK/JavaDocs/com/estimote/sdk/cloud/EstimoteCloud.html#fetchBeaconDetails-com.estimote.sdk.MacAddress-com.estimote.sdk.cloud.CloudCallback-) method of the [`Estimote Cloud`](http://estimote.github.io/Android-SDK/JavaDocs/com/estimote/sdk/cloud/EstimoteCloud.html) class instead.

For the latter to work, remember to [call `EstimoteSDK.initialize` first](https://github.com/Estimote/Android-SDK/blob/master/Demos/src/main/java/com/estimote/examples/demos/DemosApplication.java#L20), and set it up with your "app ID" and "app token," which you can generate in Estimote Cloud: https://cloud.estimote.com, the "Apps" section. (Or just use the "Blank" template in the app generator, which will generate you a blank Android Studio project with Estimote SDK already added to it, and the app ID and token already put in.)